# ”でもありやいい制度だ” Help with one line from manga translation

Tags: translation, manga

> でもありやいい制度だ

As in the title, could you help with the translation to English of this one sentence?
If you want the context, [here](http://puu.sh/drYw3/37b87ca019.jpg)

I've got an English version [here](http://mangafox.me/manga/yoroshiku_master/v01/c001/28.html) too, but it doesn't make any sense(at least to me).

Comment: Please see the answer below. Also, if you could elaborate on which part of the sentence you're having troubles with, we can help you better and explain that point more in-depth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it's ありゃ not ありや
And it's slang (or contraction?) for でもあれはいい制度だ which means "But that's a good system".  [Might have some contextual variances].

I'd also recommend asking questions in a different way.  Straight up translations aren't allowed here.  If you can dissect the sentence a bit (and maybe offer an attempt) it's more likely to not get flagged.

Comment: Helping to to clarify questions is appreciated, but please use comments for that. Posting answers as quickly as possible may not always be optimal, sometimes it's better to wait for clarifications. Irc 300 reputation should be enough for comments, you can find the "add a comment" button below the question.

Comment: Edited to explicitly answer the question (instead of implicitly).